# QT Creator just shows a white rectangle in design view

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I am following the second tutorial "Creating a Qt Quick Application" but my design view is just a white rectangle while the design view in the tutorial looks how the window does when you run it.

My design view is in the picture below. How do I make it look like a regular window instead of the checkerboard pattern?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. By default you have both QtQuick 1.1 and 2.0 imported, so I deleted the import QtQuick 1.1 line from main.qml and that seems to fix it.